# Adding a new line before lstnewenvironment

Tags: latex, listings

I'm using `lstnewenvironment` from the `listings` package to create new code blocks.
Using an example from its manual:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{pascal}
    {\hfill pascal \lstset{language=pascal}}
    {}

\begin{document}
some text before code block 
\begin{pascal}
  for i := maxint to 0 do
  begin 
    { do nothing}
  end;
\end{pascal}
\end{document}
```

This generates a `pascal` code block like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFBoh.png)

Now I want to add some text as 'tag' above the code line (at the end of that line) like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{pascal}
    {\hfill{\tiny pascal} \lstset{language=pascal}}
    {}
```

This generates:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecgys.png)

The tag text is at the same line with previous text, so I add `\\` before the tag:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{pascal}
    { \\ \hfill{\tiny pascal} \lstset{language=pascal}}
    {}
```

And tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{pascal}
    { \\ \hspace{\textwidth}{\tiny pascal} \lstset{language=pascal}}
    {}
```

But both of the `hfill` and `\hspace{\textwidth}` don't work, the tag appears at the beginning of the line above:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ct6Ts.png)

The only way I can do is manually adding a blank line between the code block and previous text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{pascal}
    { \hfill{\tiny pascal} \lstset{language=pascal}}
    {}

\begin{document}
some text before code block 

\begin{pascal}
  for i := maxint to 0 do
  begin 
    { do nothing}
  end;
\end{pascal}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUR4b.png)

My question is how to modify the `\lstnewenvironment` settings so that it can automatically add a new line between the code block and the previous text, with a tag at the end of that new line?

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/625934/36296

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{pascal}
    {  
      \endgraf  {\hfill \tiny  pascal} \lstset{language=pascal}}
    {}

\begin{document}
some text before code block 
\begin{pascal}
  for i := maxint to 0 do
  begin 
    { do nothing}
  end;
\end{pascal}

some text before code block 

\begin{pascal}
  for i := maxint to 0 do
  begin 
    { do nothing}
  end;
\end{pascal}

\end{document}
```